# predicting using multiple variables

Tags: multiple-regression

I have time series analysis for a disease, as well as climate data over the same time period which includes rainfall and temperature. I have these data for eight distinct locations (latitude and longitude points). I want to see if there is any correlation between seasonal patterns of the disease and climate, and see if climate can predict disease prevalence. I am unsure how to test this. What I have done so far is this - from the time series, I can estimate the timing of the average annual peak, and have used multivariate regression in R:

```
model = lm(disease_peak ~ latitude, rainfall_peak, temp_peak, data=mydata)
summary(model)
```

Are there any other/better ways of doing this analysis with time series data? (I have the matlab stats toolbox)

Comment: What is the resolution of your temporal data?

Comment: @BrashEquilibrium I have monthly data over 8 years

Comment: Can you post a link to your data?